# input as file path in logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

When I run a command like this(on a Windows System):

```
logstash agent -f logstash-simple.conf
```

When the logstash config file had input as stdin{} it gave the expected output but when the input was a path to the input file (file{path=>})
 it didn't give any output.

Here is my config(logstash-simple.conf) file:

```
input {
  file{
    type=>"syslog"
    path=>["C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/syslog.txt"]
  }
}

output {
 stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing file that you are looking to load, you'll need to add

```
start_postition => beginning
```

to your file input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.It is working to some extent.It is printing the output from the beginning only when I hit the backspace, otherwise it prints the tail line as it does by default. Works well on Linux/Unix systems though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You should have an empty line at the end of the file!
that worked for me